# Can attendance at congressional hearings be mandated?

Tags: united-states, congress

Does Congress in the US have the authority to mandate individuals/organizations to attend congressional hearings? I gather usually voluntary, but are the exceptions where it is required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Congress has the power to issue subpoenas, and [refusal is a crime](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/2/192). They are mandatory by default, and not appearing is only acceptable in special cases.